# Class 'builtins.NoneType' is not mapped

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have face some problem handling the database after certain logic applies.

I have a WTForm that passed the date from a leave application form. Update the `LeaveApplication` class. And after performing the calculation of the difference between `date_to` and `date_from`. I update the `LeaveBalance` class with the remaining leaves available.

However, i try to simulate this in `flask shell` session but gotten the error above.

Here's my simulation in the shell session.

```
> leave = LeaveApplication(user_id='1', leavetype_id='1',
...                        date_created=datetime.utcnow(),
...                        date_from=datetime.today() + timedelta(days=3),
...                        date_to=datetime.today() + timedelta(days=5),
...                        description='testing')


> db.session.add(leave)
> db.session.commit()
> leave_period = leave.date_to - leave.date_from
> current_leavebalance = LeaveBalance.query.filter_by(user_id='1', leavetype_id=leave.leavetype_id).first()
> updated_leavebalance = current_leavebalance.credits - leave_period.days
> update = LeaveBalance.query.get(leave.id)
> LeaveBalance.credits = updated_leavebalance
> db.session.add(update)
```

Everything is fine until i perform **db.session.add(update)** and i received the following traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ryan/PycharmProjects/LeaveVersion3/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2016, in add
    state = attributes.instance_state(instance)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Ryan/PycharmProjects/LeaveVersion3/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 163, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Ryan/PycharmProjects/LeaveVersion3/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2018, in add
    util.raise_(
  File "/Users/Ryan/PycharmProjects/LeaveVersion3/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.NoneType' is not mapped
```

I am very new to programming and I am not sure what went wrong despite reading all the existing threads. Would someone explain the problem?

Comment: I don't think you need `update`, as you are updating `leave`, assuming `leave.id` is unique.  That said it seems odd that `.get(leave.id)` seems to be returning `None`.    If you print `leave.id` is it what you expect?

Comment: Hi @snakecharmerb, I discover something but am not sure what is the solutions to it.

It seems that `LeaveBalance.credits` is no longer an object after I perform the calculation. 

For instance, when i first query `current_leavebalance = LeaveBalance.query.filter_by(user_id='1', leavetype_id=leave.leavetype_id).first()` follow by `LeaveBalance.credits`

I get the following output `<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x104e76c20>`

But after calculation and check `LeaveBalance.credits` my output is not an object anymore, instead it returns int for example `11`

Comment: Hello @snakecharmerb, I realized I didn't answer to your question. In fact, `.get(leave.id)` is actually redundant, this is just a variable id that is going to update my `LeaveApplication` table and has nothing to do with `LeaveBalance` table. If i print `leave.id` , it does have an id which is from `LeaveApplication` table. Now, if i remove this row. I am not sure what is the right way of updating the `LeaveBalance.credits`

Here's my `modals.py` https://ideone.com/DOQQ1T